# PhoneGap Local Database from SQL File

Tags: cordova

I have a SQL file which I would like to use in my HTML - how do I use it in my project?.

I will deploy my html with phonegap to use in mobile phone.

I don't have to use sql file local in the phone, how do I get information locally?

(like `select * from from person`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in the docs at the storage section http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

I guess the simplest solution would be to embed the SQL directly into JS (If its only a small amount) like the this example form the documentation:

```
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');

    //replace these lines with your table schema and starting data
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}

//this needs to be called after the phonegap event onDeviceReady() has been called
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```